# Creating a search bar with javascript & getJson, to search database and autocomplete form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I currently have a dropdownbox,

```
 @Html.DropDownList("selectSize", Model.Sizes, "--select--")
```

Because my database is to have 100s of sizes, how could I change this into a search bar, rather than having a super long dropdown box?

When the dropdown is selected, the below javascript autocompletes my userform.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[name='selectSize']").change(function () {

                $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetSize")', { sizeID: $("[name='selectSize']").val() }, function (Size) {
                    // Fill the fields according to the Jsondata we requested

                    $("#KID").val(Size["KammID"]);
                    $("#KOD").val(Size["KammOD"]);
                    $("#SID").val(Size["SpacerID"]);
                    $("#SOD").val(Size["SpacerOD"]);
                    $("#WOD").val(Size["WashersOD"]);

                });
            });

        });


    </script>
```

This script uses a controller function to contact the database and update the userform on change, the controller function is:

```
    public JsonResult GetSize(int sizeID)
    {
        var Size = db.AllSizes.Find(sizeID);
        return Json(Size, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: check out this plugin https://select2.github.io/examples.html

Comment: you can make your dropdown an input box and use the jquery Autocomplete plugin

Comment: I would check out one of the various autocomplete libraries. jQuery UI has a [popular one](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and [Typahead](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead) is great.

Comment: @KJPrice Indeed, Typehead is cool

Comment: @Benji Something I could think off is create a search input then watch for keystrokes (e.g 3-4 characters  ) -> then do your ajax -> then have a hidden div place under search input -> append items -> toggle ResultsDiv ://

Comment: would it be possible for someone to provide an example using the Select2 plugin? ive tried but it doesnt seem to pick up my @htmldropdown

Comment: Could someone provide an example for any of these lovely suggestions ? 

I can get it to work get results from the database but its not updating the userform???